# Property List Vs. NSDictionary

Tags: iphone

So I'm working on a GPA calculator app. Right now, I have my grading scale stored as an `NSDictionary` with a string for the key and a number for the value(i.e. `@"A"` --> `4.0`).

I've been realizing that I often need to access the data in different ways that `NSDictionary` does not allow. For instance, I might like to add a tag to each entry for sorting purposes. Is this the type of things a property list is designed for? Could I have a key `@"A"` with a tag `1` and a value `4.0` associated with it? 
I was thinking something like this:

```
<dict>
    <key>GradeScale</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>A_grade</key>
            <string>A</string>
            <key>point_value</key>
            <number>4.0</number>
           <key>tag</key>
           <number>1</number>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>B_grade</key>
            <string>B</string>
            <key>point_value</key>
            <number>3.0</number>
           <key>tag</key>
           <number>2</number>

        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
```

Is this the right track or am I not even close?

Edit:
So I've gone for an array of dictionaries with something like:

```
<dict>
    <key>Grade_Scale</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>string_value</key>
            <string>A</string>
            <key>point_value</key>
            <real>4</real>
            <key>Tag</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>string_value</key>
            <string>A-</string>
            <key>point_value</key>
            <real>3.7</real>
            <key>Tag</key>
            <integer>2</integer>
        </dict>
```

All I really wish to do is be able to reference a certain value by string_value, point_value, or tag. Does the above allow me to do this?

Comment: What you have here is what I would do.  Keep in mind though, as @QwertyBob says in his answer below, that this is just the way that it is stored in a file.  You would create an array, and then add one dictionary object for each grade in your grading scale, using values like in your example.  There is no need for a plist at all unless you want to save it to a file.  (Note that I agree with everything in his answer, except for the values of the dictionary because he is storing information about a grade for a specific student assignment instead of the grading system that you asked about.)

Comment: I do want to save it to a file. I want a grading scale to be persistent as once it is set, it is not likely to change.

Comment: Well, if you create it in code it will persist (unless you need to be able to make changes to it, which would be unusual for a grading scale like this) and doesn't need to be actually written to a file....

Comment: Note that a property list is normally read into the app as a NSDictionary -- the property list is just a way to represent the data in text file form.  Another way to represent the same data is JSON, which is a little easier to code in text form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A property list is just a **file format**.  NSDictionary is a **class**.  They are not interchangeable.

---

***It's not clear (to me at least) the relationship between what you want to store.*** (so there might be a better structure)

If this dictionary is to hold not the numerical values of letter grades (i.e. *"an 'A' is worth 10 points in my GPA"*) and instead the actual grades for courses:  then maybe what you need is an array holding dictionaries.

```
Array            // Holding each 'courses'.
of Dictionaries  // Where everything about the courses is stored:
                 //     {"name" => "Biology"
                 //      "grade" =>  ...
                 //      "tag"  => "science"
                 //      "scoreWeight"  =>   0.8  // this is worth 80% of my total score
```

You can then easily sort the course array however you please.

Comment: Hey thanks for responding. Currently, all I wish to store in the plist is a grading scale. I opted for an array of dictionaries